# Callback function don't set state so component try to re-render with empty values and throw error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a react component that fetching data from an api. Then depending on its state parameters i rendering one of two pages - with teams or with championships.
First it renders a list of a championships . And it works.

```js
function Main(props) {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    main: "competitions",
    id: 0,
  });
  const [value, setValue] = useState([]);
  const [filter, setFilter] = useState({
    word: "",
    date: new Date().getFullYear,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    const url = "http://api.football-data.org/v2/competitions/";
    if (state.main === "competitions") {
      //fetch for one state
      fetch(url, {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
          "X-Auth-Token": "",
        },
      })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((resp) => setValue([...resp.competitions]));
    }
    if (state.main === "teams") {
      //fetch for another
      const cupTemplate = `${state.id}/teams/`;
      const cupUrl = url + cupTemplate;
      fetch(cupUrl, {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
          "X-Auth-Token": "",
        },
      })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((resp) => {
          setValue([...resp.teams]);
          console.log(resp);
        });
    }
  });

  function toLowerLayer(num, stat) {
    //function that changes a status and id to a key of an element when you click on it
    setState({
      ...state,
      id: num,
      main: stat,
    });
  }
  switch (state.main) {
    case "competitions":
      return <Championships competitors={value} onChange={toLowerLayer} />;
    case "teams":
      return <TeamList teams={value} onChange={toLowerLayer} />;
    default:
      return <Championships competitors={value} onChange={toLowerLayer} />;
  }
}
```

Then I pass a callback that change state of an app and change condition to child component. So`<Main />` renders not `<Championships />`  but `<TeamList />`. And it isn't work.

```js
//<TeamList is same by structure and logic. But without onclick
function Championships(props) {
  const participants = props?.competitors?.map((comp) => {
    return (
      <li key={comp.id} onClick={() => props.onChange(comp.id, "teams")}>
        <Paper>
          <p>{comp.name}</p>
          <p>{comp.area.name}</p>
        </Paper>
      </li>
    );
  });
  return <ul>{participants}</ul>;
}
```

I tried to find source of a problem by log some results. Tryed to fix it somehow. But all the time it was :

> can't access property "map", props.competitors is undefined

I think problem might be that  component is re-renders when it shouldn't so I get this because second fetch isn't even starts when I get this error. But I don't know how to fix it. So how to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error message is pretty clear. Your component is being rendered while your `props.competitors` is `undefined`. It's happening because inside your `toLowerLayer` function is you settings competitions to `undefined` (you forgot about old values).

```js
function toLowerLayer(num, state) {
  setState({
    ...state, // this should solve the issue
    id: num,
    main: state,
  });
}
```

and also this inside your `then(...)`:

```js
setState({
   ...state, // this should solve the issue
   value: resp.competitions,
})
```

Also you can add simple validation to precent app from crashing, like this:

`props?.competitors?.map((comp) => {...}`

Also your `useEffect` is called extra one time cause you forgot about empty dependency array.

Change it to this: `useEffect(() => {...}, [])`

Also you can consider splitting your state to 4 different states (or at least 2), cause looks like current state properties have different change conditions.

Also, I'm not sure about this one, cause I do not see your entire code, but I feel like your onChange calls should look more like this:
`onChange={toLowerLayer}`, cause for now you are not passing any parameters to `toLowerLayer` function. Additionally you forgot about function invocation (`()`) in last `toLowerLayer` call.

Comment: Wow, thanks for help! I made some changes in my code and now it works. But I found out that in useState brackets after my fetch is somehow stops re-rendering after I change state in my callback. But when I delete them, all works fine. Except my browser throws some xhr errors about too many requests

Comment: Didn't you put something in `useEffect` dependecy array? Or maybe there is another infinite loop?

Comment: I changed a code in my question to what it looks like now. I don't think there is infinite loop somwhere (it re-renders exactly 4 times). And I fixed this with setting dependency with  state.main property only (so now it looks like useEffect(..., [state.main]))

Comment: Cool, so, do you have any other problems with your code? If you set this: `useEffect(..., [state.main]))` then it should re-render only if your component that calling `toLowerLayer` will change this, otherwise it shouldn't.

Comment: No. Thanks for help and for the time!